# can application find out if push notifications are enabled or disabled?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can my application find out if push notifications were disabled through Settings on the device? I am not talking about checking with `feedback.push.apple.com`. I would simply like to know if the switch in the Settings was set to ON or OFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]
```

If this returns `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone` which is equal to the value `0`, then the application accepts no notifications. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Turned off the notifications but it still returns 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out which kind of notifications are enabled for your app using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`.

Comment: and if the notifications are disabled?